# What is the difference between “systemctl restart” and “systemctl start”?

Tags: linux, systemd, services

I have two services A and B where B is dependent on A which means in the A's service unit i have After and Requires set to B

```
After=B.service
Requires=B.service
```

Now when i stop the service B the service A also stops. And then after stopping B when i start it, the service A is not started and i have to start it manually.

```
systemctl stop B (A is also stopped)
systemctl start B (A is not started)
systemctl start A (I have to start A manually)
```

But if the service A is already stopped and i restart service B then the B and A both are started by the systemctl

```
systemctl stop A
systemctl restart B (B and A both are started)
```

My question is what is difference between start and restart for the kind of service unit i have for A?

Comment: You say "I have two services A and B where B is dependent on A which means in the A's service unit i have After and Requires set to B". If B is dependent on a, then *B* should have the ```Requires``` statement, not A. Did you mean the other way around?